# Option -no-engine causes problems with OpenSSL build for Android

Tags: android, openssl, arm, debian

I have to build the OpenSSL 1.0.1j libraries for Android, following the instructions at http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Android, on a Debian 7 system.

My configuration options are

```
./Configure dist -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine
```

The build fails due to the error

```
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `../../include/openssl/engine.h', needed by `rsa_lib.o'.
```

(Remark: Using `linux-generic64` instead of `dist` made no difference)

Providing the option `-no-rsa` leads to complaints from `dsa_lib.o`. It 
also does not make sense to disable RSA and DSA, does it?

I read the NEWS file, http://wiki.openssl.org/ and questions here on SO, 
but could not find a solution.

Any suggestions?

Besides that: What is the actual meaning of `-no-engine`? According to my understanding,
ENGINE is the interface to the crypto algorithms of openssl. Why should it be possible to disable it at all?

Comment: *`./Configure dist -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine`* - Three problems here. First, the instructions state to use `configure` *after* setting the cross compile environment (not `Configure`). Second, there is no `dist` in the instructions. Third, `-no-XXX` is wrong, it should be `no-XXX`. I fixed the wiki pages for the third issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Option -no-engine causes problems with OpenSSL build for Android ...
> ./Configure dist -no-ssl2 -no-ssl3 -no-comp -no-hw -no-engine

You can safely omit the `no-engine` option. The option was used to reduce the size of the binary.

---

> What is the actual meaning of -no-engine? According to my understanding, ENGINE is...

That's a good point, and I can't answer it. But I can say I've used the procedures on the wiki page for a few years, and I know OpenSSL still works (compiles/links/runs) when the no-engine option is used.

Maybe something has changed for 1.0.1j. I did not upgrade (meaning I did not build 1.0.1j for Android and iOS) because I'm not interested in that [Downgrade SCSV](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-tls-downgrade-scsv-00) to accommodate the browsers and their broken-shit, insecure practices of retrying with SSLv3.

---

> Using linux-generic64 instead of dist made no difference...

The cross-compile script ([setenv-android.sh](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/File:Setenv-android.sh)) sets the paths to the Android NDK tools ***AND*** it sets a few key environmental variables. Of them, `CROSS_COMPILE` are `ANDROID_DEV` are critical. From the tail of [setenv-android.sh](http://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/File:Setenv-android.sh):

```
# For the Android toolchain
# https://android.googlesource.com/platform/ndk/+/ics-mr0/docs/STANDALONE-TOOLCHAIN.html
export ANDROID_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/$_ANDROID_API/$_ANDROID_ARCH"
export SYSROOT="$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export NDK_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export ANDROID_NDK_SYSROOT="$ANDROID_SYSROOT"
export ANDROID_API="$_ANDROID_API"

# CROSS_COMPILE and ANDROID_DEV are DFW (Don't Fiddle With). Its used by OpenSSL build system.
# export CROSS_COMPILE="arm-linux-androideabi-"
export ANDROID_DEV="$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/platforms/$_ANDROID_API/$_ANDROID_ARCH/usr"
export HOSTCC=gcc
```

Configuration for Android is picked up through `SYSTEM` and `ARCH`. Once Android kicks in, `CROSS_COMPILE` and `ANDROID_DEV` are utilized.

Because of the environmental variables, all you need to do is `configure no-ssl2 no-ssl3 ...`.

Comment: Your answer helped me solving my problem. The procedure on the wiki seems to work with 1.0.1j, too. Thanks.

Comment: @Hermann - very good. Out of curiosity, are you using Android NDK or Debian's arm-embedded?

Comment: I am using the Android NDK. 
Addmittedly, I also had to modify `/.Configure` by adding the target architecture 'armv5te'. It doesn't seem possible to enforce this architecture through the script alone. Right? (Maybe this is worth another SO question)

Comment: @Hermann - Yes, you have to tweak `Configure` in that case. Also, OpenSSL's choice of `CFLAGS` leaves a lot to be desired. They diverge drastically (in some cases) from Android's own build settings. Most troubling is related to ABI and floating point. Be sure to add `-mfloat-abi=softfp` too.

Comment: @Hermann - by the way, I wrote many pages on the OpenSSL wiki, including the one on Android. I'm going to try to clear up the `no-engine` recommendation soon. I need to do some research first.

Comment: Regarding the last question, here's a [README](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/README.ENGINE) that gives an idea why `no-engine` was added at all. It's a way to provide alternative implementations of cryptographic algorithms (such as hardware acceleration).

Answer (score 0):

A symbolic link to `engine.h` is not created when building OpenSSL with `no-engine`. I just added

```
(cd include/openssl ; ln -s ../../crypto/engine/engine.h .)
```

to my build process.